# How to properly store events' recurrences and complex reminders in a mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, time

I would like to store events' recurrences in a mySQL database (additionally, I'm working with Symfony 3 and Doctrine ORM).

For instance:
Every 3 days / Once a week / Bimonthly / Half-yearly / Once a year

What is the best way to store this kind of data in order to be able to easily perform queries on it?

Moreover, I want to create complex reminders based on these recurrences.

For instance:
From February to September: once a week and from October to January: bimonthly

How could I manage reminders' dates calculation? Should I store the start date and calculate the next dates each time, or should I store only the next date when a reminder is marked as completed?

(My use case: set reminders for watering plants).

Thank you a lot for sharing what do you think about!

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set events in MySQL itself or as pogeybait suggests, you can write a cron job and a command.

If you need the server to do something outside of the database, you likely need a cron job. If it's all contained within the database (such as just updating a "plants_need_watering = false" column to "plants_need_watering = true" without having to send an email or start some other program) then I'd say MySQL events are more suitable.

Here's a pretty good tutorial on events (although, I had to play around with the delimiters when I tried it): https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Here's a simple event I wrote. You can see how it just updates a db column based on the date. I set the status of a my own "event" (not a MySQL event, but an entity from my application) to "Voting is closed." if the "voting_end" date is past today and this runs every 12 hours so I know I can't accidentally miss one. This is just entered once as regular SQL, you can practice and check results on a local dev machine by setting the schedule to every hour or so, check to see that it worked, then switch back to the actual desired timeframe to run the event: every week, every month, etc.

```
        SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
        CREATE EVENT switch_event_status
        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 12 HOUR
        DO
        UPDATE event_status
        INNER JOIN
        event ON event_status.id = event.event_status_id
        SET
        event_status.value = \'Voting is closed.\'
        where 
        event.voting_end <= cast(now() as date);
```

Also, here's the Symfony documentation on writing console commands. It's actually pretty easy. http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html

And cron jobs to kick the console command off: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux machine, you can use cron jobs to check however often as you'd like. Id create a console app to do this so the cron job is easier to call. It's easier than you think to create the console apps. For the database I'd store general info about each event (name, title, description) and an interval field which would say how often that even should trigger an notification. Initially store the current date and time when the event is added and then when the interval time passes trigger then notification and store the date and time of the notification. That's the simplest way I can think of. See more here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html for console commands.